# Is it possible to duplicate triggers in Google App Maker?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I was wondering when someone creates a trigger with a certain handler, should we look first if the trigger with that certain handler function already exists? If it does then remove it then add the new trigger.

Or every time a trigger is created ( lets say accidentally a button with a function that creates a trigger was clicked twice ), the old one gets overridden?

Answer (score 0):

When a trigger is created, the method [returns](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#create) a new instance of the [Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger) class. This means that it is not possible to duplicate triggers since each one will have a unique id, which you can get by calling the method [getUniqueId()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger#getUniqueId()).

So in your example:

> lets say accidentally a button with a function that creates a trigger was clicked twice

Two triggers performing the same thing will be created. So ideally, the best thing to do is to create a trigger and save the unique id to an [apps script property](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties#setpropertykey-value) using a unique name. For example:

```
var emailTrigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger("sendEmailReport").timeBased().everyHours(2).create();
var triggerId = emailTrigger.getUniqueId();
PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("emailTriggerId", triggerId)
```

Of course, you'll have to implement a way to check if the property already exists with a value. If it does, then you skip the creation of a new one. If it doesn't, then you proceed to create a new one. So in summary, it should look something like this:

```
function createNewTrigger() {  
  var existingTrigger = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("emailTriggerId");
  if(!existingTrigger){
    var emailTrigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger("sendEmailReport").timeBased().everyHours(2).create();
    var triggerId = emailTrigger.getUniqueId();
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("emailTriggerId", triggerId);
  } else {
    //return "Trigger alredy exists";
    //throw new Error("Trigger alredy exists");
  }    
}
```

**BONUS**: To [delete the trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#deletetriggertrigger), you'll have to check if it already exists too. Something like this should get you in the right direction:

```
function deleteTrigger(){
  var existingTrigger = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("emailTriggerId");
  if(existingTrigger){
    var allTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    for(var i=0; i<allTriggers.length; i++){
      if(allTriggers[i].getUniqueId() === existingTrigger){
        ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(allTriggers[i]);
        break;
      }
    }
  } else {
    //return "Trigger does not exists";
    //throw new Error("Trigger does not exists";
    //createNewTrigger();
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that Apps Script does not expose others' triggers to the calling user: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36764532

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
function createTrigger(handlername) {
  var triggersA=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  var found=false;
  for(var i=0;i<triggersA.length;i++){
    if(triggersA[i].getHandlerFunction()==handlername){
      found=true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(!found){
    //Create trigger here
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that Apps Script does not expose others' triggers to the calling user:  Hence, this solution will only work if the app is being run as the developer. If you are planning on deploying the app as the developer, this solution is better than mine.

Comment: @Morfinismo...I see the problem now.  I didn't realize that getProjectTriggers doesn't get all project triggers.  It just get's the ones for the current user.  Unfortunately, if some user goes in to their project triggers and deletes the one that is currently stored in property service then I guess they wouldn't be able to create any new triggers for that handler.